# Go back to specific Fragment in Navigation Drawer from Activity

Tags: java, android, mobile

I would like to know how do I go back to a specific Navigation Drawer Fragment from a activity.

For example:

Navigation Drawer Menu Options:
Home Fragment
Products Fragment (Lists products, the user can click product to edit product activity)
Other Fragment

Now when I go back (Toolbar back button & android back button) from the Edit Product Activity it goes back to the MainActivity which has the Navigation Drawer, but it goes to the Home Fragment. I would like when the user goes back on the Edit Product activity to go to the Products Fragment.

How do I achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my issue by adding `android:launchMode="singleTop"` to my MainActivity class in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried navigation component? https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started

Comment: link only answer is not preferred as the link might get broken and then answer is of no use!

Comment: It won't work for my senario from what I understand. I would like the activity to go to back certain fragment of the navigation drawer. The Navigation component only works with fragments only.